# Proper utilization of Ampere’s Law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, capacitance

I am tasked with finding the magnetic field due to a bus bar, which seems to have the exact same set up as Problem 7.62 in the fourth edition of Griffiths' textbook on Electrodynamics.

[image]

To which I have found a solution for here:

[image]

I am confused with the following in the answer, assuming in the graphic $\mathbf B$ points along the -x direction, with z going up the page and y in the left and right:

1. Why can we assume this can be approximated to a parallel plate capacitor with that electric field? How come we could ignore fringe effects or the like?
2. Why is $\mathbf B$ the way it is? I attempted to derive it myself using Ampere's Law.

[image]

I am told in my question, that is almost identical to this but not exactly, that the conducting plates ribbons have surface current $I_0$ running across the plates as $I$ runs across the plates in the illustration. Does this mean my Amperian loop is oriented the way it is in my graphic so as to enclose a full slice of the surface current? I'm not exactly sure the loop had to be the way it was when I drew it but I'm trying to replicate $B$ from the solution.

The only way I can get the solution to agree is if I consider enclosing just one of the plates (let's say the top one) with a loop of dimensions $w$ by $z$, where $z$ is some displacement in the z direction but it doesn't matter because only the $w$ side length of Amperian loop will contribute. So, the loop will only get a non-zero contribution for when the path and $\mathbf B$ is parallel, which is the path of the loop under the plate.

$$\implies B w = \mu_0 I_0$$

$$\implies B = \frac{\mu_0 I_0}{w}$$

But if this is the right way to go about this, then why must I choose $w$ as one of the dimensions of my loop? Surely, for any length $l$ for the dimension of the loop in the x direction, as long as it is greater than $w$ it should enclose the same amount of current, and thus the result being the same.

So I should be able to argue:

$$B(x) = \frac{\mu_0 I_0}{x}$$

Where $x$ is the length of the Amperian loop in the x direction, and thus $B$ is no longer a constant field. In addition, I would get the same result if I did the bottom plate.

$$B= \frac{\mu_0 I_0}{w}$$

Noting that this field only applies between the two plates. Why are the two not added together for the net magnetic field magnitude? Surely both currents need to be taken into account.

3. Finally, I would certainly agree $\mathbf B$ points along the x direction if the ribbons were infinite sheets in the xy plane, but given the finite width why can we assume this is true?

Comment: Saying that $h<<w$ essentially tells you to ignore end effects, and that you can treat $B$ as constant between the plates for this problem.  It is a common approximation.

Comment: @BillWatts Why does this imply $B$ is constant? I thought it would mean you approximate the ribbons as a sheet of charge and thereby the electric field is constant between the plates.

Comment: I believe that the conditions on $h$ and $w$ mean that they expect one to work the problem as though $w$ is infinite for Ampere's law.   I agree with you in that it seems they are ignoring the contribution of the bottom strip to compute $B$.